# Sql:does not give interval correctly from the table

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a table containing a field with the following value:

```
+00 08:00:00.000000
```

I write sql:

```
select delivery_trigger_time from  mars
```

But my request returns me a different format:

```
0 18:0:0.0
```

How can this situation be corrected?
how can I do so that when select it does not overwrite 0?

Addition. This is how I get it, although in the oracle database itself, it lies as I described above.
[image: This is how it looks at my request]

Comment: should be a time-zone-problem (server / your workstation). there are many ways to configure your client-time-zone ... the detailled information can be found here https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch4datetime.htm ... don´t know where to put in intellij, sorry. workstation-environment-parameter could be the easiest way to fix

Comment: What data type is that column? Looks like an `interval` (which sounds like a strange choice given the column's name)

Comment: Yes this is an interval, the name is strange, I agree, this is a third-party system. At intervals, will the solution be different?

Comment: An interval is a _duration_ ("this took me 3 days and 5 hours"), not a "point in time" (as in "today at 17:30"). Unless the column stores the "duration" of the delivery, this does seem like the wrong choice. However, if your "request" displays the result incorrectly, then it is most certainly caused by your code that doesn't properly deal with the interval value. Interval values are not subject to time zone conversions, so that won't play a role there

Comment: When you say *'does not overwrite 0'* are you referring to the display format? What about the 10 hour difference?

Comment: Yes, I mean the display format. Suppose if there is 10:00, then I will get 10: 0. Perhaps it is in jdbc, but I can not find a specific reason yet

Comment: Is `08` vs `18` (10 hour difference) part of the question, or a typo?

Comment: A typo, I beg your pardon